# Displaying a foreign key's field in an admin tabular inline

Tags: python, django

How would I go about displaying a foreign key's field (not the id field) as a read only column in a tabular inline?

For example, the admin page I have is used for editing items that display on a slider.  The tabular inline I have represents a list of stories:

```
class SliderItemInline(TabularInline):
    model = SliderItem
    ordering = ['position']
    fields = ('position', 'story', 'active')
```

I would like to display **story.status** as a readonly column on the inline as well, but I'm not sure how to do that.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I know a lot of time has passed after asking this question, but maybe it will be useful to someone else.

Here's one way to do it:

```
class SliderItemInline(TabularInline):
    model = SliderItem
    ordering = ['position']
    fields = ('position', 'story', 'active', 'story_status')
    readonly_fields = ('story_status',)

    def story_status(self, obj):
        return obj.story.status
```